# How this code convert to arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I have a problem with implement this python algorithm to arduino. Help me to do this..

```
def Process(lst):
    for k in range(len(lst)):
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if abs(lst[i]-lst[i+1])==2 and lst[i+1]!=0:
                for j in range(i,len(lst)-2):
                    lst[j]=lst[j+2]
                lst[-1]=lst[-2]=0
    return(lst)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please try to do it yourself and ask a question when you have a specific problem with your code. Nobody here will do it for you, but everybody will help you do it by yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas to get you started:
You don't really have lists in C on the Arduino. A data structure you could use there is an array. See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Array for more info.

Passing around arrays to e.g. functions is done via a pointer to the first element of the array. Since this is not enough information to determine the size of an array you typically also provide the size/number of elements. This leads to a possible signature of the function:

```
int* process(int* lst, int numberOfElements) { ... }
```

`range(n)` in Python returns all numbers from 0 to n-1. In order to do the same in C and iterate over the elements of an array you basically loop from 0 to numberOfElements-1. You can then access the elements in the array by their index, i.e.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    (...)
    lst[i] = lst[j + 2];
}
```

Hope this is enough information to get you started.